# Can an Aegis/Soulknife manifest weapons and armor while in Form of Dragon I?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, class-feature, psionics, polymorph

In the event an [Aegis](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/classes/aegis/)/[Soulknife](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/classes/soulknife/) managed to get themselves a fairly long duration Form of Dragon I, from Polymorph Any Object for instance, does it legally follow that said character should be allowed to manifest his weapon and armor on that form? Or have I missed a clause/FAQ/ruling somewhere?

As his type hasn't been changed, nothing he needs merged with him, and his class abilities specifically call out that they are 'appropriately sized' and 'always proficient', I'm inclined to think it's RAW legal - but I may have been blinded by flavor text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Yes, but...

A polymorphed soulknife can certainly manifest their mind blade. *However,* depending on the form, the lack of hands will be an issue. You need a free hand to wield the weapon (per the base rules on using weapons), and nothing in the soulknife allows you to telekinetically float a mind blade (except aesthetically).

Aegii, on the other hand, are free to form their astral suit in whatever form they like. There's no restriction on their shape for that, and it'll fit their current form just fine.

Comment: See, if this were 3.5, I'd know which sources to get that reasonably prove the ruling they don't have hands, but the type entry for dragons simply states they aren't proficient with weapons - also, Craft is on their class skill list. This suggests tool use, which suggests manual dexterity, even if they don't have proper hands. Can you cite a PF reference?